# Complicated sorting in Python

Tags: regex, sorting, python-3.x

I need to sort a list of strings.

However, I do not want to sort it using the first character, so I cannot use `.sort()`

I have a list:

```
records = ["Bibble - 1300 / 2000",
"Jim Foo - 900 / 2000",
"Bibble - 1600 / 2000",
"Bibble - 1000 / 2000"]
```

I want to sort by their score out of 2000.
I want an output that looks something like this:

```
>>> Jim Foo - 900 / 2000
Bibble - 1000 / 2000
Bibble - 1300 / 2000
Bibble - 1600 / 2000
```

In the example above, I sorted it by smallest to largest. I also want to know how I would sort this list biggest score to smallest score.

I've tried `.sort()`, but It's nothing like what I want. `.sort()` sorts it with the first character which I do not want:

```
>>> records.sort()
>>> records
['Bibble - 1000 / 2000', 'Bibble - 1300 / 2000', 'Bibble - 1600 / 2000', 'Jim Foo - 900 / 2000']
>>>
```

Is there anyway of doing this, possibly in regular expression?

Is it also possible, so if i were to add more scores into the list I would still be able to sort it this way?

Comment: you need to specify `key` when you call `sort`.

Comment: @HuStmpHrrr What do you mean? Sorry, I do not know what a key is. I mean, I do in dictionaries but not in this example.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `sorted` function with a proper `key` and use `re.split` :

```
>>> import re
>>> sorted(records,key=lambda x:int(re.split(r'[-/]',x)[1].strip()))
['John Smith - 900 / 2000',
 'Bob Foo - 1000 / 2000', 
 'Bob Foo - 1300 / 2000', 
 'Bob Foo - 1600 / 2000']
```

The `sorted` function sort your list based on its key function, and your key split your elements with `re.split` with function as following :

```
re.split(r'[-/]',x)
```

the pattern `[-/]` split your string based on `-` or `/`.

for example :

```
>>> re.split(r'[-/]',"Bob Foo - 1600 / 2000")
['Bob Foo ', ' 1600 ', ' 2000']
```

and then you need to `strip()` to remove the leading and trailing spaces. then convert to int and sort your list based on that value!

Comment: This works and is great because it's on one line. However, could you explain what it does at what point?

Comment: (r'[-/]',x) I'm a little confused with this line, could you go over it in your answer?

Comment: @BlaZe added in answer!

Comment: Works perfectly and now I understand how it all works. Will accept this as the answer asap!

Answer (score 0):

```
def f(e):
    a, b = map(float, e.split('-')[1].split('/'))
    return a / b

records.sort(key=f)
```

Comment: As long as b is always 2000, as specified, it can be ignored. But this would work even if that changes.  A could then be returned as an int rather than a float.

Comment: @TerryJanReedy yes, more generic than required.

Answer (score 0):

Use the `key` attribute of the sort method:

```
import re
records.sort(key = lambda x: int(re.split('[-/]', x)[1]))
```

`re.split` splits `x` into parts whenewer it encounters a `-` or `/` character - that's what the `[-/]` expression stands for. Then we select the second part, convert it to an integer and use this value for sorting.

Answer (score 0):

```
>>> import re
>>> records = ["Bob Foo - 1300 / 2000",
"John Smith - 900 / 2000",
"Bob Foo - 1600 / 2000",
"Bob Foo - 1000 / 2000"]
>>> def get_score(s):
    m = re.match(r'.* - (\d+) / 2000', s)
    return 0 if m is None else int(m.group(1))

>>> sorted(records, key=get_score)
['John Smith - 900 / 2000', 'Bob Foo - 1000 / 2000', 'Bob Foo - 1300 / 2000', 'Bob Foo - 1600 / 2000']
```

`get_score` will calculate the key of each record, and `sort` or `sorted` will sort `records` according to this value.

Answer (score -2):

1. `sort` accepts optional key parameter. E.g. if you want to sort int list by power of number you can do something like `[-3, 2, 1].sort(key=lambda x: x *x)`
2. I'm pretty sure you can write function which extracts number 1000 from "Boo Foo - 1000 / 2000". Hint: use `split`.